# Pyright exhaustive check on literal only works for parameter, not properties

Tags: python, python-typing, pyright

This works:

```py
def test(it: Literal['a', 'b']) -> str:
    if it == 'a':
        return 'a'
    elif it == 'b':
        return 'b'
    # No error, exhaustive
```

But this doesn't:

```py
@dataclass
class Foo:
    foo:  Literal['a', 'b']

def test(it: Foo) -> str:
    foo = it.foo
    if foo == 'a':
        return 'a'
    elif foo == 'b': # Correctly infers that foo is Literal['b'] without the check
        return 'b'

    # Error, must return str
```

Why?

Comment: `pyright` bug? Seems to work in `mypy`; no error reported on this code, but does report a missing `return` statement if the type is changed to `Literal['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Comment: (`mypy` also correctly infers the type of `foo` as demonstrated by using `reveal_type`; can you use that with `pyright`?)

Answer (score 0):

It's apparent that this is a PyRight bug that it can't infer the type of `foo` from `foo = it.foo`.

For now, you would have to explicitly type hint `foo` with:

```
foo: Literal['a', 'b'] = it.foo
```

Demo [here](https://pyright-play.net/?code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoAySMApiAIYA2AsAFCiRQAm5M5AxpeQM7cneZsufCzace3OnQACojl151xvKADEwYAFx0ouqMA2bdRUhUoBtAOTlLAGiiWARpYC6U2kxLBY-GAApiI3UwAEooAFoAPihuGBBtWj19Q0JiMiorG3snVygAXkwYADoDMB09JG9S-ILrSwSkpJASGABXEBQHG3LdEkpK5LAah2cGxt1mto6RyyA)